# Método burbuja problema

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un método burbuja que ordena los datos de mi vector, necesito que los datos resultantes cada vez que recorra el ciclo se ordenen, por ejemplo

```
public void OrdenarBurbuj()
    {
        int temp;
        for (int i=1; i<edades.Length;i++)
            for ( int j=edades.Length-1; j>=i; j--)
            {
                temp = edades[j - 1];
                edades[j - 1] = edades[j];
                edades[j] = temp;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español :D podrías colocar un título adecuado por favor, explicando a detalle, el formato se le da usando "control k", caso contrario es difícil de entender la pregunta, aquí entre todos nos apoyamos, estamos con todo el power 2.0!!! Siempre :D. Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

si consultas el [pseudocódigo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja) del algoritmo te darás cuenta de que te falta poner el `if` en el segundo `for`.

```
    int temp;
        for (int i = 1; i < edades.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = edades.Length - 1; j >= i; j--)
            {
                if (edades[j - 1] > edades[j])
                {
                    temp = edades[j - 1];
                    edades[j - 1] = edades[j];
                    edades[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Con eso ya estaría:

[image: Resultado]